# Create logic for SMART attributes

Tags: php, sql, logic

Im building an product inventory application wich allows users to create a master template for a product, for example

```
    CPU 
      - cpu_option1
      - cpu_option2
      - cpu_option3
    MEM
      - mem_option1
      - mem_option2
      - mem_option3
```

When I select `cpu_option1` then `mem_option2` and `mem_option3` are not available.

```
These rules are not pre-programmed, these rules are created/changed by any user
```

I'm searching far and wide for examples of these kinds of smart attributes and how to implement the logic/design pattern.

ontopic: im looking of a design pattern of storing and using these rules

Comment: is 'When i select "cpu_option1" then "mem_option2" and "mem_option3" are not available.' this the actual situation or should it be this way?

Comment: It should be like this, the customer wants to apply these rules so a marketeer can use these rules  to build a product not knowing the limitations of the hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DB could look like this:

- Compontents (id, name)

  1 - CPU

  2 - MEM
- Options (id, name)

  1 - cpu_option1

  2 - cpu_option2

  3 - cpu_option3

  4 - mem_option1

  5 - mem_option2

  6 - mem_option3
- Components2Options (cid, oid)

  1 - 1

  1 - 2

  1 - 3

  2 - 4

  2 - 5

  2 - 6
- Options2Combine (oid1, oid2)

  1 - 4

  2 - 5

  3 - 5

  3 - 6

This example shows that

- cpu_option1 works with mem_option1
- cpu_option2 works with mem_option2
- cpu_option3 works with mem_option2 and mem_option3

If this answer your question?

Comment: this is the version i already made up, (option x supports y). i wanted to see if my version maybe had a design flaw for future features. thank you for taking the time for answering my question, if no one else answers i will accept yours!

Comment: Maybe... (I just think a minute about it) it could be possible to define 'properties' as an extra table and than define rules with these properties... for example socket as a propertie of the cpu and than the same propertie for the motherboard... so the programm could check on his own if properties fit and decide if the component could fit... BUT just maybe